# Strange Visual Studio Behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

my computer started doing something strange the other day and its seriously annoying. I haven't made any changes to the system but for some reason now when I double click on a visual studio solution file, it won't open. The only way I am able to open projects is to open the program and then go to file -> open and navigate to the solution.

Also, I have the program pinned to my taskbar (Windows 7) and I have it set to run as administrator but whenever I click on the button it still asks me if I want to allow the program to make changes to my computer. Any thoughts on how I can get things back and running the way they used to?

Comment: I ran into this problem in the past and I found I could open solution files doing the following `Right Click -> Open With -> Visual Studio 2010`. Don't have a solution though.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn off UAC
2. Test
3. The solution can be to change the Microsoft Visual Studio Version
   Selector to run as an admin. To do so navigate to
   %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv or
   %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv (64-bit),
   right click on VSLauncher.exe and select Properties. Go to the
   Compatibility tab and check “Run this program as an Administrator”.
4. Test
5. If the above didn't work try to also remove remove the contents of
   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0. If you have any precious settings backup the folder before deleting it.

Comment: Should he/she also reformat the computer by the way ? :) :) It's simple file association question posted in C# (??) group. The @Dylan answered him in first comment

Comment: Didn't see Dylans answer until mine was posted. Also, Dylan didn't provide a solution but a possible workaround.

Comment: I have tried setting Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector to run as Admin, as well as going into the IDE and changing devenv.exe to run as admin and the shortcut itself. I can at least now open solution files through double clicking but no matter what I do it still asks me to permit the program to make changes. There was nothing in the AppData\Roaming.... folder

Comment: If you run VS as admin the userfolder you should check is the one for admin.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably lost the file association. Right click on a solution file and click open with and then select VS2010 from the list and ensure the checkbox is ticked to make it the default.

As to opening VS2010 as Admin I use a trick (read it somewhere, but can't remember where).

I have a separate admin Icon on my desktop (etc) with the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "VS2010 - Admin"
```

Then in Task Scheduler I have a task:

```
Name: VS2010 - Admin
Location: \
Desc: Runs VS2010 with Admin privileges
Action: Start a Program
Run with Highest Priveleges checked
Program: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
Allow to be run on demand
```

Then when you run the icon, it will trigger the schedule which will launch VS as admin :D